# PHP auth not perfectlyworking in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, authentication

PHP authentication code is:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

Issue is the message `Basic realm="My Realm"` is not shown in Chrome but it works as per our expectation in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There was an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=602301) reported recently on the Chromium issue tracker regarding the problem, which was merged with [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544244).